# Maven Profiles and Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, maven-3

If I have 2 maven profiles for a WAR application like this:

```
mvn clean install -Pdevelopment
mvn clean install -Pproduction
```

and I import it in Eclipse to run in Tomcat, how to I tell Tomcat to use one profile or the other?

Comment: mvn tomcat:run -Pdevelopment or mvn tomcat:run -Pproduction ?

Comment: but it doesn't use the Tomcat server inside Eclipse. But if there is no solution for my question, I think this may be the closest one

Comment: Why wouldn't it use the server within Eclipse? You would need to configure the plugin to deploy to the temporary server location created by the WTP plugin in Eclipse.

Comment: My idea is to make Tomcat/Eclipse understand the build (which is already correct), and not the other way around. I'd like my pom to be independent of the environment, pointing to a temporary folder of a Eclipse's plugin wouldn't achieve this.

Comment: The question is valid for any Server type

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can activate the `maven profile` at the `Eclipse` by using the following step: -

1. `Right click` at your project and select `properties` .
2. At the `Properties windows` select `Maven`.
3. At the `right hand panel` you will see `Active Maven Profiles` text box.
4. Please enter your `profile name`, e.g. `development` or `production`.

I hope this may help.