# Deploy dynamically project on Tomcat from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically deploy a **maven** project on **eclipse** and have the same result as if it was packaged in a WAR.

I noticed that when I right-click the project and choose "run as" and then choose tomcat the project deployed does not work properly but when I generate the war and place it manually it works fine.

That means everytime I change something in the code I have to generate a war and deploy it manually on the server.

Is there a **tomcat** config that I can use to have an output when I run from eclipse similar to when i generate a war?

I'm using tomcat 6.0.26 and eclipse Neon 3.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you don't use String boot, don't you? If yes, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542108/hot-code-deploy-tomcat-with-maven

Comment: When you say it's a Maven project, does Eclipse know that? Are the Eclipse m2e-wtp plug-ins installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't configure the maven profiles when I ran the project from eclipse which explains why I had different outputs when deploying the project from a war and directly from eclipse. The answer here [Maven Profiles and Tomcat in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280858/maven-profiles-and-tomcat-in-eclipse) explains how to configure maven profiles when you run on server from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can ...

In general the steps are:

1) Turn your existing project into a maven project by adding a `pom.xml` like this into the project root folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.yourcompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>yourApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <name>Your Web Application</name>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

    <!-- Add your dependencies as needed. -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

2) Rightclick the project and `Configure` -> `Convert to Maven Project`

3) In Eclipse `Servers` view add an Apache Tomcat.

4) Rightclick the Tomcat server and `Add and Remove ...` -> `Add` your project.

5) Launch the Tomcat in `debug` mode.

Now eclipse will deploy the project in exploded .WAR format, replacing and therefore hot deploying resources on every change and compiling Java classes on change.
If you do not alter Java method or class signature, changes in Java source code and resources take effect instantly without the requirement to restart Tomcat or the web application.

Comment: The project is already a maven project. The problem is that when I do the steps you described the exploded war content is different from the war generated using a maven goal. When I compared the 2 outputs I found that some jars are missing so I added them manually which broke the project.

Comment: @Nabil can you provide relevant parts of your POM in your question showing how you declared the dependencies to this jars? Sounds like we are getting closer to the actual problem.